# ng-admin won't display dropdown stored values

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, ng-admin

I really hope somebody can help me with an issue using ng-admin.
I created a dashboard with ng-admin and all works fine. There is only one issue, on models where I used boolean field with chooices. Of course there is displayed a dropdown field, but on edit an entry the correct value from database isnt't selected. I also tried to use filterChoices, but won't make any changes... it is still nothing selected after open edit view.

Here is my field declaration:

```
nga.field('copiable','boolean')
                .label('Copy')
            .choices([
                      { value: null, label: 'Please choose' },
                    { value: true, label: 'Yes' },
                      { value: false, label: 'No' }
                  ])
            .filterChoices([
                    { value: null, label: 'Please choose' },
                    { value: true, label: 'Yes' },
                      { value: false, label: 'No' }
                  ]),
```

And here you can see my JSON response object:

```
{xxx, xxx, "copiable":"1"}
```

Here is the MySQL structure:
[image]

Maybe I did a bad mistake here and somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If there is someone out there... who has the same issue.
I got the solution now!

MySQL stored boolean as integer 0,1 and my backend with PHP SLIM API takes these values and put it in the JSON response.
But ng-admin expects the values "true" or "false" only and can't work with 0,1 ... So I only had to customize my API response and now it's working fine!

Maybe this helps someone....
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map/transform` approach:

```
nga.field('copiable', 'boolean')
        .label('Copy')
        .choices([
            { value: null, label: 'Please choose' },
            { value: true, label: 'Yes' },
            { value: false, label: 'No' }
        ])
        .map(value => !!value)
        .transform(value => value ? 1 : 0)
```

`map` will convert incoming from API `1` or `0` to `true` or `false` accordingly.

`transform` wise versa convert `true` or `false` to `1` or `0` before send data to API